# Using .xlsx js package, how can skip multiple header rows

Tags: typescript, xlsx

I'm attempting to read a .xlsx sheet but skip the first 8 header rows

```
import { readFile, utils } from "xlsx";

const workbook = readFile('foobar.xlsx');
const worksheet =  workbook.SheetNames[1]

const data = utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {defval:"", header: 8 })
```

This is obviously not working.   Can anyone please assist?   What's the correct `header` value to skip multiple header rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're converting the file to JSON, can't you just modify the json afterwards? Then it might just be skipping the first 8 items in the array

Comment: I think the headers are doing some weird things which are making the ability to manipulate the resulting JSON painful (getting some properties with a key of `__EMPTY: 13000`)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).